# Can you test JavaScript / JQuery code embedded in HTML page with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, jasmine

How can I use Jasmine or other tool to test the JavaScript / JQuery that is embedded inside a web page like in the example below?

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- usual includes --> 
</head>
<body>

    <span id="myspan1"></span>
    <span id="myspan2"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#myspan1').html('something'); 

            $('#myspan1').click(function(){
                $('#myspan1').html('something else');
            }); 

            doStuff();

            function doStuff() { 
                $('#myspan2').html('stuff done');
            }

        }); 

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to "test"? Can you not just copy that source code into an .html file on your computer and open it in your browser?

Comment: I want to write automated unit tests for JavaScript / JQuery event handlers and functions.  That is the purpose of Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

I simply assume that you want to ensure that the "stuff done" appears on the page after a reasonable amount of time.

```
describe("My page", function () {
    it("should say stuff done after max 500 ms", function () {
        waits(function () {
            return $('#myspan2').html() == 'stuff done';
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahus1/QP2Pk/

Normally you would put your javascript code into a external file.

Then you can setup a test page that includes the minimum elements from the normal page, plus Jasmine.

In this test page I didn't wait to run Jasmine when the page was finally loaded, but works anyway.

Br Alexander.